# Express.js router - match empty string?

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

How do I made path a like `api.get('/view/:search/:userid', search)` work with `/view//12`, giving `params.search` an empty value?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following:

```
api.get('/view/:search?/:userid', search)
```

or if you define a new route

```
api.get('/view//:userid', search)
```

Comment: Does not work: `GET /view/z/z 200 8ms - 2b
GET /view//z 404 2ms
`

Comment: What if you define a new route covering that case *api.get('/view//:userid', search)*